# Set the index field to be not_analyzed and then do wildcard query, does it appear low performance?

Tags: elasticsearch

Set the index field to be not_analyzed and then do wildcard query, does it appear low performance? ......Are there any issue to lead it appear low performance????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Wildcard queries are not very efficient.

The inverted index works very well because there is an entry in it for every term that you want to search on.  However, your wildcard queries are not using the inverted index as it is intended.

For instance, if you search on `"foo*"` it has to find all terms in the inverted index that begin with `"foo"`, then search on all of them. That can be very slow and memory intensive.

If you know that you want to do wildcard searches, then you should analyze your data accordingly.  Use an ngram or edge-ngram tokenizer to analyze your field, in order to index partial matches.  This will allow the inverted index to function as intended.